# Реализация Stack для хранения int* на C-и

Tags: c

Есть реализованная структура данных [Stack на C.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-data-structure-introduction-program/)

```
// C program for array implementation of stack
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// A structure to represent a stack
struct Stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    int* array;
};

// function to create a stack of given capacity. It initializes size of
// stack as 0
struct Stack* createStack(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->array = (int*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return stack;
}

// Stack is full when top is equal to the last index
int isFull(struct Stack* stack)
{   return stack->top == stack->capacity - 1; }

// Stack is empty when top is equal to -1
int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{   return stack->top == -1;  }

// Function to add an item to stack.  It increases top by 1
void push(struct Stack* stack, int item)
{
    if (isFull(stack))
        return;
    stack->array[++stack->top] = item;
    printf("%d pushed to stack\n", item);
}

// Function to remove an item from stack.  It decreases top by 1
int pop(struct Stack* stack)
{
    if (isEmpty(stack))
        return INT_MIN;
    return stack->array[stack->top--];
}
```

Я поменял его чтоб он хранил вместо int int*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct StackNode
{
  int* data;
  struct StackNode* next;
};

struct StackNode* newNode(int* data)
{
  struct StackNode* stackNode =
    (struct StackNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct StackNode));
  stackNode->data = data;
  stackNode->next = NULL;
  return stackNode;
}

int isEmpty(struct StackNode *root)
{
  return !root;
}

void push(struct StackNode** root, int* data)
{
  struct StackNode* stackNode = newNode(data);
  stackNode->next = *root;
  *root = stackNode;
  printf("%d pushed to stack\n", data);
}

int* pop(struct StackNode** root)
{
  if (isEmpty(*root))
    return INT_MIN;
  struct StackNode* temp = *root;
  *root = (*root)->next;
  int* popped = temp->data;
  free(temp);
  return popped;
}
```

Но он понятно что не работает из-за строки
`return INT_MIN;`

Как поменять эту строку чтоб она работала?

Comment: Возвращайте `NULL`, если не хотите как-то иначе реагировать на аварийную ситуацию...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом варианте в стеке хранились *целые числа*. В случае, если из стека нечего было извлечь, вы возвращали какое-то *целое число* (`INT_MIN`).

В вашем варианте в стеке хранятся *указатели* на целые числа. В таком случае, если из стека нельзя ничего извлечь нужно возвращать какой-нибудь *указатель*. Проще всего - `NULL`.